# How to cut edges in the cycles of a graph such that it should remain connected?

Tags: graph-theory

A question has come into my mind. Consider a connected graph in which all the 4-membered cycles are known. Suppose that $n$ is the number of linearly independent 4-membered cycles ($n$ is unknown). How to delete $n$ edges from the graph such that it should remain connected (the number of vertices cannot be changed)? Could an efficient algorithm be constructed for this problem? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: How do you define "independent cycle" and "n cut"? Perhaps you can provide an example and/or graphic.

Comment: I have improved my question.